# Cold boot code in C

Tags: c, memory, boot

Is there any one who can explain this code to me?
This is an old exam question and i can't find an answer on the net.

> ```
>  void (*x)();
>  x=0xFFFF0000;
>  printf("1"); x();
>  printf("2"); x();
>  printf("3"); x();
> ```

Comment: What, specifically, don't you understand?  Are you familiar with function pointers?

Comment: I don't understand what that code does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On classic real-mode x86 architectures, you could trigger a system boot by doing an unconditional JMP to address 0xFFFF0000.

The code is basically defining `x()` as a function, and setting the function's in-memory address as 0xFFFF0000. When you invoke the function, the system would do `CALL 0xFFFF000` or similar at the assembler level, and jump directly to the BIOS boot code, triggering a system reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
void (*x)();
```

which is a pointer to a function returning void and accepting void as input. You point it at memory location 0xFFFF0000 which is where the cold boot function is located according to your exam.

Then you do 3 printfs() followed by 3 invocations of the function which is located there. But I don't really see the point. Is there any question? Is this all that was in the exams question?